# wider histograms hide narrower ones in df.plot.hist

Tags: python, pandas, plot, histogram

Hi need to plot the histograms of grouped variables as

```
df.groupby(['Variable1', 'Variable2']).plot.hist(bins=50)
```

Is there a way to make all the histogram visibles? Plot first the bigger ones and then the smaller ones?

[image]

the results for alpha = 0.1 is still very confused..

```
df.groupby(['Variable1', 'Variable2']).plot.hist(bins=50,alpha=0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: Use a lower value for `alpha`?

Comment: Try alpha = .5 in plot.hist

Comment: I ve tried with alpha =0.5 and alpha = 0.1 but it is still very confused... is it possible to plot the bigger ones on the background?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the opacity of your plot by changing the value of `alpha` .

`df.groupby(['Variable1', 'Variable2']).plot.hist(bins=50,alpha=0.5)` or use any alpha value of your choice

Alternatively, you can plot the variables one after another(which is probably not what you're asking for)

Here's a demo:

```
p = np.random.normal(4, 1, 1000)
s = np.random.normal(4, 2, 1000)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': p ,'B': s})
```

Plotting the dataframe

```
df.plot.hist()
```

[image]

```
df.plot.hist(alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Plotting a one variable at a time,

```
df['A'].plot.hist()
df['B'].plot.hist()
```

[image]

Changing the sequence of plotting;

```
df['B'].plot.hist()
df['A'].plot.hist()
```

[image]

Comment: I ve tried with alpha =0.5 and alpha = 0.1 but it is still very confused... is it possible to plot the bigger ones on the background?

Comment: Yes. But then you have specify each variable at a one time.

Comment: Can you post some reproducible data so I can add that to the answer?

Comment: Just a comment - even though this is technically possible (and alpha solution is correct), the result will most probably be visually confusing. With multiple histograms, it's perhaps better to use line or scatter representation.